# Cause a connected socket to accept new messages right after .BeginReceive?

Tags: c#, vb.net, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, sockets

Basically I've made a socket connection. Here's my WaitData method:

```
    public void WaitForData()
    {
        State state = new State();
        state.Client = socket;
        //issue first receive
        state.Client.BeginReceive(state.Buffer, 0, state.Buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ServerReadCallback), state);
    }
```

This is called whenever my socket is waiting for data (I want it to wait for data all the time).
So whenever a new message has started to be received (.BeginReceive is called) I want my main thread to call WaitForData again so it'll keep accepting messages.
How would this be done?

(btw I can't call WaitForData in the ServerReadCallback since it would block for the actual receiving of the message).

Sorry if my description is messy; I found it rather hard to describe.

Answer (score 1):

In your ServerReadCallBack routine once you've finsished processing the message, issue another BeginReceive ie:

```
    State state = new State();
    state.Client = socket;
    //issue first receive
    state.Client.BeginReceive(state.Buffer, 0, state.Buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ServerReadCallback), state);
```

Bear in mind however if your messages are variable length, then the data read in a buffer may be part of a message; the whole of a message; or the whole of a message plus part/whole of another message. So your ServerReadCallback needs to be able to deal with this - something along the lines of:

```
    private void OnDataReceived(IAsyncResult asyn)
    {
        ReceiveState rState = (ReceiveState)asyn.AsyncState;
        Socket client = rState.Client;
        SocketError socketError = SocketError.TypeNotFound;

        if (!client.Connected)
        {
            // Not Connected anymore ?
            return;
        }

        _LastComms = DateTime.Now;
        _LastIn = _LastComms;

        int dataOffset = 0; 
        int restOfData = 0;
        int dataRead = 0;
        Boolean StreamClosed = false;
        long rStateDataLength = 0;
        long LastrStateDataLength = 0;

        try
        {

            dataRead = client.EndReceive(asyn, out socketError);
        }
        catch (Exception excpt)
        {
           // Your code goes here..
        }

        if (socketError != SocketError.Success)
        {
            // Has Connection been lost ?
            OnConnectionDropped(client);
            return;
        }

        if (dataRead <= 0)
        {
            // Has connection been lost ?
            OnConnectionDropped(client);
            return;
        }

        while (dataRead > 0)
        {
            //check to determine what income data contain: size prefix or message
            if (!rState.DataSizeReceived)
            {
                //there is already some data in the buffer
                if (rState.Data.Length > 0)
                {
                    restOfData = PrefixSize - (int)rState.Data.Length;
                    rState.Data.Write(rState.Buffer, dataOffset, restOfData);
                    dataRead -= restOfData;
                    dataOffset += restOfData;
                }
                else if (dataRead >= PrefixSize)
                {  //store whole data size prefix
                    rState.Data.Write(rState.Buffer, dataOffset, PrefixSize);
                    dataRead -= PrefixSize;
                    dataOffset += PrefixSize;
                }
                else
                {  // store only part of the size prefix
                    rState.Data.Write(rState.Buffer, dataOffset, dataRead);
                    dataOffset += dataRead;
                    dataRead = 0;
                }

                if (rState.Data.Length == PrefixSize)
                {  //we received data size prefix 
                    rState.DataSize = BitConverter.ToInt32(rState.Data.GetBuffer(), 0);
                    rState.DataSizeReceived = true;
                    //reset internal data stream             
                    rState.Data.Position = 0;
                    rState.Data.SetLength(0);
                }
                else
                {  //we received just part of the prefix information 
                    //issue another read
                    client.BeginReceive(rState.Buffer, 0, rState.Buffer.Length,
                       SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(socketReadCallBack),
                          rState);
                    return;
                }
            }



            //at this point we know the size of the pending data

            // Object disposed exception may raise here
            try
            {
                rStateDataLength = rState.Data.Length;
                LastrStateDataLength = rStateDataLength;
            }
            catch (ObjectDisposedException Ode)
            {
                StreamClosed = true;
            }
            if (!StreamClosed)
            {

                if ((rStateDataLength + dataRead) >= rState.DataSize)
                {   //we have all the data for this message

                    restOfData = rState.DataSize - (int)rState.Data.Length;

                    rState.Data.Write(rState.Buffer, dataOffset, restOfData);
                    //Console.WriteLine("Data message received. Size: {0}",
                    //   rState.DataSize);

                    // Is this a heartbeat message ?
                    // This is my own thing - you may not need this..
                    if (rState.Data.Length == 2)
                    {
                        // Yes
                        HeartBeatReceived();
                    }
                    else

                    {
                       // Handle the received messsage

                        DecodeMessageReceived(GetStringFromStream(rState.Data));
                    }

                    dataOffset += restOfData;
                    dataRead -= restOfData;

                    //message received - cleanup internal memory stream
                    rState.Data = new MemoryStream();
                    rState.Data.Position = 0;
                    rState.DataSizeReceived = false;
                    rState.DataSize = 0;

                    if (dataRead == 0)
                    {  
                        //no more data remaining to process - issue another receive
                        if (_IsConnected)
                        {
                            client.BeginReceive(rState.Buffer, 0, rState.Buffer.Length,
                               SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(socketReadCallBack),
                                  rState);
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                        continue; //there's still some data to process in the buffers
                }
                else
                {  //there is still data pending, store what we've 
                    //received and issue another BeginReceive
                    if (_IsConnected)
                    {
                        rState.Data.Write(rState.Buffer, dataOffset, dataRead);

                        client.BeginReceive(rState.Buffer, 0, rState.Buffer.Length,
                           SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(socketReadCallBack), rState);

                        dataRead = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Stream closed, but have we read everything ?
                if (LastrStateDataLength + dataRead == rState.DataSize)
                {
                    // We're equal, get ready for more
                    //no more data remaining to process - issue another receive
                    if (_IsConnected)
                    {
                        client.BeginReceive(rState.Buffer, 0, rState.Buffer.Length,
                           SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(socketReadCallBack),
                              rState);
                    }
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    // We should have more..
                    // report error ?
                }
            }

            // If we've been disconnected, provide a graceful exit
            if (!_IsConnected)
                dataRead = -1;

        }
     }
```

In this code my rstate is:

```
public class ReceiveState
{
    public byte[] Buffer = new byte[1024]; //buffer for network i/o
    public int DataSize = 0; //data size to be received by the server
    public bool DataSizeReceived = false; //whether prefix was received
    public MemoryStream Data = new MemoryStream(); //place where data is stored
    public Socket Client;   //client socket
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to do something like this:

```
private ManualResetEvent _connectionAccepted;

public void WaitForData()
{
    while (true)
    {
        _connectionAccepted.Reset();

        socket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), state);

        _connectionAccepted.WaitOne();
    }
}

private void Acceptcallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
     _connectionAccepted.Set();

     Socket socket = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
     Socket handler = socket.EndAccept(ar);

     State state = new State();
     state.Client = handler;

     handler.BeginReceive(state.Buffer, 0, state.Buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ServerReadCallback), handler);
}
```

So, basically, you're looping indefinitely.  When you get a connection, you start to accept it; when you're in the code to handle accepting the connection, you signal the main loop that it can keep going.  Then you EndAccept, which gives you a second socket - and that socket is used to communicate with the client, thus allowing the initial socket to continue accepting new connections.

Only one call to WaitForData() is necessary - that's where the loop is - so you may want to bring that up a level for naming or whatnot.  But this is the general idea.

Comment: I think what you've addressed here is being able to accept new connections from different clients; as opposed to continuing to receive messages from the same client. I could be wrong....

Comment: @andrew:  You're 100% right.  Must have gone crazy.  If his interest is to keep receiving from one connection, then you've got it covered below.